# What is the correct solution of $x^{2/2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, radicals

Ok I get that
$$\left(\sqrt x\right)^2 = x$$
and
$$\sqrt{x ^2} = |x|.$$

I can explain this to myself when I insert $-1$ for $x$. With complex number $i$ I obtain those solutions. Fine.

Now when we have the power rules
$$\left(b^m\right)^n = b^{m n}.$$

Now we can write $\sqrt x = x^{1/2}$. Thus, $\left(\sqrt x\right)^2 = x^{1/2 \ 2}$ but then $\sqrt{x ^2} = x^{2 \ 1/2}$.

So my question is, is $x^{2/2}$ equal $x$ or $|x|$ and why?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define your range and domain, and how you define $\sqrt x$. I was reading a thread on this site recently that argued the ins and outs of whether $\sqrt{25}$ was $5$ or $\pm 5$

Comment: Note that the equation $(a^b)^c = a^{(bc)}$ is correct only under certain restrictions.  Such as $a>0$ and $b$ real.  Find it in your textbook for a complete description of the restrictions.  We frequently have contradictions posted in math.se obtained by disregarding theses restrictions.

Answer (score 6):

Let us start with the final question. The answer is $x^\frac22=x^1=x$.

However, you should not use the notation $\sqrt x$ when $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(0,+\infty)$, because then $x$ has *two* square roots and it is, in general, not clear which one is the one that you have in mind. On the other hand, if we accept that $\sqrt x$ is *some* square root of $x$, then it is trivial that $\sqrt x^2=x$.

But if $x\notin\mathbb R$ then *no* square root of $x^2$ is equal to $\lvert x\rvert$. So, I suggest that you don't write that $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$, unless $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misconception that the power rule

$$(b^n)^m=b^{nm}$$

holds for any base and any exponent.

For example,
$$((-1)^2)^{1/2}\ne(-1)^{2\cdot1/2}.$$

---

There is no doubt that $$x^{2/2}=x^1=x.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in [0,\infty)$ then it is $$\left(\sqrt x\right)^2 = x$$ and $$\sqrt{x ^2} = |x|.$$

If $x\in (-\infty,0)$ then it is $$\sqrt{x ^2} = |x|$$ and the LHS of $$\left(\sqrt x\right)^2 = x$$ doesn't exist unless you consider complex numbers.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to say in my comment but couldn't work out how to word it for the life of me! So thank you, and have an upvote